# Signature and cusp geometry of hyperbolic knots

Tags: knot-theory, machine-learning

Nature recently published a [paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-021-04086-x) titled “Advancing mathematics by guiding human intuition with AI”. Using the power of <strike>linear algebra and calculus</strike> machine learning, the authors link "geometric" invariants of knots like the Chern-Simmons invariant and "algebraic" invariants like the Jones polynomial by proposing and proving a novel theorem:

$$|2 \sigma() − \operatorname{slope}(K)|≤ c _1\operatorname{vol}(K)\operatorname{inj}(K)^{−3} + c_2$$

where $\operatorname{vol}(K)$ is the hyperbolic volume of a knot, and $\operatorname{slope}(K)=Re(\lambda/\mu)$ where $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are the longitudinal and meridional translations of $K$, respectively, and $c_1$, $c_2$ are constants independent of $K$. (The theorem is proven in [The Signature and Cusp Geometry of Hyperbolic Knots](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2111.15323.pdf).)

Here are some concrete questions (related to a subjective question I have which is not appropriate here):

> Question 1: Does this theorem have any implications to established problems in knot theory? (The authors mention non-hyperbolic Dehn surgery.)

> Question 2: Does the slope of a knot as defined above appear in other guises elsewhere in knot theory? (The authors claim no.)

Comment: The title seems completely different from the questions you ask in the body of the text.

Comment: For the question, it might be better to link the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.15323 which contains more mathematical discussion of this result, the slope, and the signature. The title of this question could be changed to "The signature and cusp geometry of hyperbolic knots", the title of that paper, or "The signature and the slope of hyperbolic knots". I feel this title is going to be unnecessarily confusing if someone asks a (new) question about generalities of applying AI to mathematics.

Comment: I agree the original title was confusing.  I changed the title to correspond to the paper being discussed.

Comment: Looking at the result, the main thing that strikes me is the constraint on the slope entirely in the language of topological invariants.  So you could think of this theorem as telling you a range of possible slopes on a cusped hyperbolic manifold, in order for this manifold to embed in $S^3$.  I don't know if this theorem is better than you can do using other techniques, but that is the main feature that pops out at me.

Comment: The original title was the name of the paper, though the new one makes the mathematical question clearer.

Comment: Reading the edits (and taking into account the original title), as well as the language of the question as it stands now, this question seems to be posed either 1) by someone at DeepMind to hype their paper and increase visibility by asking related questions about their result (lately they seem to have been promoting their research rather aggressively; if one reads the Nature paper, their abstract is ridiculous, as the language they use is [...]

Comment: indicative of scientific marketing departments (overly optimistic, using a type of survival bias to selectively highlight only those few milestone conjectures that were experimentally discovered); also, their framework isn't as new as one might think it is, see e.g. link.springer.com/article/10.1007/JHEP09(2017)157 ) or 2) by someone who is rather very skeptical of the impact of their method and tries to see, aside from the AI aspect, how important their mathematical result is considered to be by the larger community.

Comment: @user43263: The question is asked from a place of extreme skepticism (I think this was clearer in my original posing of the question, but it was edited to be less sassy). I am curious if there is any actual value of this kind of work in the mathematical community.

Comment: I also find it slightly offensive that Nature, one of the top scientific journals, expressly does *not* publish pure math, but if you use ML to make a conjecture no mathematician is interested in and *then* prove it, suddenly it is deemed worthy of their periodical.